# Is it possible to rewrite WHILE loop with Rest-Assured requests attempts using Java Stream api

Tags: java, java-stream, junit5, rest-assured

I got a method which sends request via Rest-assured and if response fails to meet condition (response status code is 200) it makes several attempts unless i get 200 as a response status code

```
protected Response getResponseWithRetries(Map<String, Object> requestBody, String token, String url) {
    Response response = null;
    int statusCode = HttpStatus.SC_BAD_GATEWAY;
    int count = 0;
    while (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK && count < 3) {
        response = getResponse(requestBody, token, url);
        statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        count++;
        sleep(5000);
    }
    return response;
}
```

But is it possible to rewrite this loop with Stream api? I am struggling with understanding if i can apply it in my case. To start with i have no response collection to stream. But i also don't want to make several request to build it (when they are all successful for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IntStream.range` to replace the `count` part of your condition and then filter the response for the http status code and return the first occurrence with `findFirst`.

```
Optional<Response> response = IntStream.range(0, 3)
    .mapToObj(i -> getResponse(requestBody, token, url))
    .filter(r -> r.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
    .findFirst();
return response.orElse(null);
```

If it's likely that you return `null` instead of a response it would make sense to change the return type to `Optional<Response>`.

---

If you want to get the last response even if it failed you can do 2 iterations and then use `Optional.orElseGet` to do the last `getResponse` call if no positive status code was returned in the 2 iterations.

```
Optional<Response> response = IntStream.range(0, 2)
    .mapToObj(i -> getResponse(requestBody, token, url))
    .filter(r -> r.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
    .findFirst();
return response.orElseGet(() -> getResponse(requestBody, token, url));
```

Comment: thanks that looks like something i need, the only change i need is to take last response if all attempts are failed.

Comment: I've edited the answer to give an example on how to always return the last attempt.